# How much bonus ranged damage do Walls of Babylon give?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

> **Walls of Babylon**  
> The walls of Babylon increase the damage output of all the city's ranged attacks and increase the city's defense. 
>  +6 Armour 
> +100 HP

It doesn't however state how much the bonus damage is. Are there any numbers?

Also does it stack with the pantheon ability below?

> **Goddess of Protection** 
>    +30% increase in city  Ranged Combat Strength

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shield icon - "Armour" you've called it - is actually a city's *combat rating*. As with military units<sup>1</sup>, the combat rating represents both the offensive and defensive capabilities of city. Therefore, the Walls of Babylon provide +6 to the city's base combat rating.

And yes, this will stack with any other boosts to a city's combat rating. In general, when it comes to stats modifiers in the game, all direct + or - modifiers are applied to the base value first, then all % modifiers are summed and applied as a single multiplier applied (so +20% and +30% is applied as +50%, *not* a compounded +56%).

<sub>1. Except for ranged units that have a ranged rating as well - used for attack - while the combat rating for them is defense only.</sub>